# How to resolve 403 Forbidden on Symfony website

Tags: symfony, permissions, apache2

I just started a project and when I try to access the website I get this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

Here's the config of my website:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName portfolio.lxc

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/portfolio/public
        <Directory /var/www/portfolio/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled my website like this

```
a2ensite portfolio
systemctl reload apache2
```

And then this error. When I looked on the Internet, it was said to allow "Options FollowSymLinks" but it's already allowed on my conf. I tried

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/portfolio/
```

But I still get this error.

Comment: Anything in the error log? Is selinux enabled?

Comment: No nothing seems to fit the error in the log. What is selinux? I don't think I use it ^^

Comment: Have you installed the apache package? `composer require symfony/apache-pack` ([Adding Rewrite Rules](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html))

Comment: Yes I just did, I also added "Options +FollowSymLinks" in the same time in my config, and it worked. I just don't know which helped resolved the issue. if I remove the option in the config it still works so I guess adding the apache-pack resolved it! Thanks